# Add an index to an inherited field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-inheritance

I have many models which need timestamps and cache control and therefore inherit from [`TimeTrackable`](https://github.com/ambv/kitdjango/blob/ba115ce2462b31cf78702faa045285ce78ff138f/src/lck/django/common/models.py#L158) from `lck.django`, a mixin library I am using.

However, for some reason the `created` and `modified` fields defined in `TimeTrackable` are not indexed, even though many other fields in the same mixin library are, and I use sorting based on these fields heavily to varying degrees based on the model and would like to index one or both of them in my postgres database.  (I am open to the idea that indexing on these fields is not what I actually need, but I think it's a pretty clear-cut use case for indexes.)

My understanding is that due to quirks in Django's inheritance model, if I just try to override those fields with fields of the same name, plus an index, the system will try to create two identically-named fields and choke on `syncdb`.

Is there any good way to index them?  I can think of a few options:

- copy/paste the code of `TimeTrackable` into my app (not DRY but at least the consequences are predictable)
- add a separate index step in a `south` migration or syncdb hook or something (seems fragile, and confusing for someone trying to tell what columns are indexed by looking at the application code, given some columns are indeed explicitly indexed in the model files)
- index it manually in postgres after the application is initialized (I have to hand this application off to a client, so I would like to minimize manual deployment steps)
- somehow use/abuse the ["index together" meta field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#index-together) to index individual fields instead of its intended use (no idea what the consequences of this would be, were I to try it)

Are there any other good methods of doing this?

Comment: Since you would like the answers to be "suitable to my use case" you might want to give us some hints about what that use case actually is. Why are you "not sure I can be confident it will be applied in every case"?

Comment: @GarethRees Sorry, I'll edit to elaborate on why I don't feel adding indexes manually is suitable.  As for south or syncdb, the reason I'm skeptical is because that would be procedural instead of declarative: for instance, what if someone later removes the fields on one of the models with a migration and then adds them back? It looks like that would work fine because there is no index in the model, but the indexes would be dropped.  And worse, they would exist if you syncdb from a fresh db but not if you migrate with south.  Not a huge practical obstacle, but it seems ugly and fragile to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up on was abusing `index_together` on the child model.  Ugly or not, it's the most convenient way to index an individual field (there's no check that `index_together` tuples have more than one member) and it's declarative and relatively clear to read.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking at solutions for django<1.5 use `uniqe_together`